# MongoDB: Duplicate key error index with replaceOne

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a collection with index

```
{
   "v" : 2,
   "unique" : true,
   "key" : {
     "username" : 1
   },
   "name" : "username_1",
   "ns" : "heroku_25.player"
}
```

I run the query

`db.player.replaceOne({"username":"QdAKu"}, {"username":"QdAKu","name":"Blaksm","timePlayedTotal":4807724700}, {upsert:true});`

I get the error

`MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: heroku_25.player.$username_1 dup key: { : "QdAKu" }`

I am using nodejs, with `mongodb 3.5.5`.

What could be causing the error? If the query is `{"username":"QdAKu"}` and the key is only `username`, I should never have the error for duplicate key index.

The error doesn't happen all the times, only rarely on the production server.

Comment: What is your MongoDB server version?

Comment: @Oleg mongod version: 3.6.12 (MMAPv1)